# How to use a button's event with defined picturebox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba

I thought I'd make a very simple fps game. I have all the graphics but I have just one error.

The error is that you can spawn an enemy into the game by clicking a button. Using that button, you can spawn as many enemies into the game as you like. To do this I have written the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim enemy As New PictureBox
  enemy.Image = My.Resources.enemy.png
  Me.Controls.Add(enemy)
End Sub
```

But, to shoot the enemy, you have to click on it and I am not sure on how to make that happen as the 'enemy' variable is not actually on the form until the program is started and the button is clicked.

I have tried this but it has not brought to me any success:

```
Private Sub Enemy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enemy.Click
```

Comment: Attach the event when you create the new `PictureBox` - in the function you've presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the event handler yourself:

```
Dim enemy As New PictureBox
enemy.Image = My.Resources.enemy.png
AddHandler enemy.Click, AddressOf Enemy_Click
Me.Controls.Add(enemy)
```

On the clicked method side, you would get which PictureBox was clicked by the sender object:

```
Private Sub Enemy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim pb As PictureBox = sender
  // do stuff
End Sub
```